# The 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_centerInParent' attribute is not declared

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin

I am programming for Android at Xamarin.
I am trying to center a progress bar in a Relative Layout. However I am receveing this message: The 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_centerInParent' attribute is not declared.

Look at the code bellow:

```html
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="35"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">
            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout file has missing android xml namespace.
Add xmlns:android attribute in your layout

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
```